# $\liminf_n f_n=f $ $a.e.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions, such that $(f_n)_n$ converges in measure to $f$. 
I want to prove that $\liminf_n f_n=f$ $a.e.$

I tried to prove it, but I get nothing, I am thankful if someone can give me a hint.

Comment: almost surely (in probability), I will correct it

Comment: If it holds for the $\liminf $ then it also holds for the $\limsup $ by considering $(-f_n) _n$. Therefore by your statement we get that convergence in measure implies convergence almost everywhere, but we know that that is not true... So from there you already see that the statement cannot be true.

Comment: yes you're right, but like I said what if $f_n$ are non negative??

Comment: I think, I find a similar question here (the limit in measure is 0): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589353/f-n-converges-in-measure-implies-liminf-f-n-0-a-e

Comment: Does it matter whether it is nonnegative or not? I don't think so.

Comment: if you're saying though then the prove that user141614 provided in here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589353/f-n-converges-in-measure-implies-liminf-f-n-0-a-e   is also false

Comment: In fact if $(f_n)$ are positif then the statement is true, if not then it is false, so the nonnegativity is a sufficient condition

Comment: The statement given there assumes the limiting function $f=0$... So it is not the same thing here

Comment: Yes, in that special case the statement is true. See my (edited) answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not correct. For all $n\in\mathbb N$ set

$$f_n\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R, \quad x\mapsto(-1)^k1_{[l\cdot 2^{-k},(l+1)\cdot 2^{-k}]}(x),$$

where $k= \lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor$ and $l=n-2^k$. Then
$$f_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0 \quad \text{in measure (with respect to Lebesgue's measure),}$$
but
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = -1 \quad\text{and}\quad \limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = 1 \quad \text{for all $x\in[0,1]$.}$$

However, if each $f_n$ is non-negative and the limit in measure is 0 almost everywhere, the statement is true. In this case, $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f_n\ge 0$ a.e. is trivial and it remains to prove the converse, which follows if we find a subsequence that converges to 0 almost everywhere. But such a subsequence has to exist thanks to the subsequence characterisation of convergence in measure.

Comment: What if $f_n$ is positive?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Just take $g_n:=f_n+2$ with $f_n$ as in my answer.

Comment: to be more precise $\liminf_n |f_n|=|f|$ $a.e$

Comment: See above, it's still wrong.

Comment: don't we have $\liminf_n |f_n| \leq |f|$ a.e

Comment: I think by subsequence

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: Also, $|f| \leq |f-f_n|+|f_n|,$ and $(|f-f_n|)_n$ converges measure to 0, so $\liminf_n|f-f_n|=0$ a.e

Comment: if what I said is true, then we proved Fatou's lemma for measure convergence

Comment: Yes, the statement becomes true if $f_n$ is non-negative and $f\equiv 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: |$f_n-f|$ converges to 0 in measure, then $\liminf_n |f_n-f|=0$a.e

Comment: we can conclude from the inequality $|f| \leq |f-f_n|+|f_n|$ that $|f| \leq \liminf_n |f_n|$a.e then the equality a.e since $\liminf_n |f_n| \leq |f|$a.e by subsequence   it that correct?